# "All Options" in Drop Down List Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a list of car types and their respective sales. I want to create a drop-down list that brought me each of the types of cars and that there is an option to "include all", how can I do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spqsu.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
={"include all"; FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>"")}
```

and create dropdown from there